# Creating a column with mean statistical values in a tennis dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I am working with a tennis dataset and want to transform it for an enhanced informativity. I had been searching for a solution to my problem but have not found anything yet.

I want to make columns that will show mean statistical values for previous matches of each player in each row. As you understand, in every row there should be some values for player 1 and some values for player 2 with their mean statistical indexes for previous games. Moreover, it is needed to take values when a player is either 1st or 2nd in previous matches.

Here is a part of the dataset:

```
  Player 1     Player 2     P1_Prct1stIn    P2_Prct1stIn    P1_Prct1stWon   P2_Prct1stWon
1 Djokovic N.   Raonic M.     0.644444      0.576923            0.724138    0.844444
2 Cilic M.      Wawrinka S.   0.450000      0.610390            0.861111    0.787234
3 Nishikori K.  Murray A.     0.630252      0.530303            0.720000    0.757143
4 Raonic M.     Thiem D.      0.637931      0.545455            0.864865    0.6666671
5 Djokovic N.   Goffin D.     0.614035      0.468085            0.828571    0.590909
6 Wawrinka S.   Murray A.     0.611940      0.588235            0.658537    0.866667
7 Nishikori K.  Cilic M.      0.635135      0.545455            0.638298    0.809524
8 Raonic M.     Murray A.     0.632812      0.609589            0.740741    0.617978
9 Nishikori K.  Djokovic N.   0.636364      0.636364            0.514286    0.821429
10 Murray A.    Djokovic N.   0.542373      0.721311            0.843750    0.590909
```

Prct1stIn - percentage of 1st serve in

Prct1stWon - percentage of 1st serve rally won

So I need columns made using this dataset like this:

```
P1_PREV_MEAN_Prct1stIn
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
 0.644444
 0.610390
 0.630252
 0.607427
 0.6326935
 0.57604233
```

It is great if one will show me how to take mean values of, for example, 10 last matches of the player as well.

I would be grateful for any help in deciding this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd create a useful `pd.MultiIndex`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        ('P1', 'Name'), ('P2', 'Name'),
        ('P1', 'Prct1stIn'), ('P2', 'Prct1stIn'),
        ('P1', 'Prct1stWon'), ('P2', 'Prct1stWon')
    ])

d1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values, df.index, mux).sort_index(1)
print(d1)
```

[image]

---

Now I'd `stack` and `groupby` `'Name'` and `apply` `expanding` `mean` that's been `shift`'d

```
f = lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift()
g = d1.stack(0).groupby('Name')[['Prct1stIn', 'Prct1stWon']]
d2 = g.apply(f).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1)
d1.join(d2, rsuffix=' Prior Mean')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, this does not work when dealing with the entire dataset (here I showed only part of it).

Comment: Are you planning on showing more of it?  Or sharing what went wrong?

Comment: Yes, no problem! Here is the link to watch it: https://github.com/maanisimov/Tennis-matches-analysis/blob/master/Analysis%20of%20Tennis%20Bets%20Formation%20in%20the%20BM.ipynb.
There are links to sites with original information as well. 
I suppose Russian language will not confuse you because dataframes are to be watched. But if it is a problem I can make an English version.

Comment: I think it would be difficult to show the whole information here.